# Cannot access * before initialization

Tags: angular

I have a module that declare and export a component while setting up a service :

```
export const GOOGLE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<InjectionConfig>('ExternalChannelIoModule');

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, NgbDropdownModule, NgbTooltipModule, SharedPipesModule],
  declarations: [AddressAutocompleterComponent],
  exports: [AddressAutocompleterComponent],
})
export class ExternalGoogleModule {
  static forRoot(config: InjectionConfig): ModuleWithProviders<ExternalGoogleModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ExternalGoogleModule,
      providers: [
        GooglePlacesService,
        {
          provide: GOOGLE_TOKEN,
          useValue: config,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

inside my App.module I am importing that module root :

```
import : [
    ExternalGoogleModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.tokens.googlePlaces,
    })
]
```

and in my `shared.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ExternalGoogleModule,
  ],
  exports: [

    ExternalGoogleModule,
  ],
})
export class AppSharedModule {}
```

Now the above works fine, but I have another module where I need to use `ExternalGoogleModule` and this module do not import `AppSharedModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //...
  ],
  exports: [
    //...
  ],
  imports: [
    //...
    ExternalGoogleModule,
  ],
})
export class FeatureMap {}
```

this `FeatureMap` is imported inside `AppSharedModule`

the problem I face is, when launching the app I get

> Cannot access 'AddressAutocompleterComponent' before initialization

which is the component declared inside `ExternalGoogleModule`.

I tried playing with the import order, but no success. So I am wondering what I could change

EDIT : I checked for circular dependency, and I couldn't find any. I am using NX and he can detect circular dependency but do not complain too. I will retake a look, but I am pretty sure there is none.

Comment: @GRD thanks for the reply. This Module is mine, and I didn't setup any method `.forChild()` I am copying other service like `TranslateModule` where you only do forRoot() in app module, and simply ` TranslateModule` in childs 
`

Comment: I followed what they do hjere : https://javascript.plainenglish.io/understand-angulars-forroot-and-forchild-f27fbc41cb7b
It does the exact same error, I replace all child moduleimports using `forChild`

Comment: thanks, yeah something very similar, I will stry to understand from there what is wrong with mine.

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed the problem but I am need to investigate further. I am using library and there is one `index.ts` that export modules etc.. for each library

In `app.module`

I was doing the following

```
import {
  //stuff
} from '@frontend/shared';
import { ExternalGoogleModule } from '@frontend/external-google';
```

knowing that both import point to a file like

`@frontend/shared`

```
// various export
export { SharedModule } from './lib/shared.module';
```

`@frontend/external-google`

```
// various export
export { ExternalGoogleModule } from './lib/external-google.module';
```

Problem is `SharedModule` in the above barrel was importing a subModule of that library, that was using `ExternalGoogleModule`, but `ExternalGoogleModule` was imported in the line just under.

Switching to

```
import { ExternalGoogleModule } from '@frontend/external-google';
import {
  //stuff
} from '@frontend/shared';
```

I wonder if there is good practice for this situation